# Zip contents to upload

Tags: phonegap-build

Witch contens do I have to zip in the file I have to upload to phonegap build?

I'm not sure about this. I have compress the www folder and config.xml, but if I have included GoogleService-Info.plist and google-services.json I suppose I have to include this, right?

Do I hvae to include the rest of folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add config.xml file in wwww folder. also create a folder inside www named xml and copy the same config.xml file in xml folder before you zip